# PDF link with target="_blank" opens in new tab for one pdf, downloads for other

Tags: html, pdf

I have a site where I have 2 links on the page:

```
<a href="/somePDF1" target="_blank"> A PDF</a>
<a href="/somePDF2" target="_blank"> Another PDF</a>
```

PDF1 opens in a new tab and displays (tried chrome, firefox, IE, safari).
PDF2 opens a new tab for a split second, but then downloads it rather than displays in the tab.

I'm not trying to force any behaviour, I want to honor the browser's choice for what to do with target _blank.
But I don't know why these 2 PDFs behave differently on the same page with the same anchor settings.

The only superficial difference I can see is the first file is 200k and the second 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/somePDF1" target="_blank> A PDF</a> 
<a href="/somePDF2" target="_blank> Another PDF</a>
```

**Just close correctly target attribute with "** Please, see below.

```
<a href="/somePDF1" target="_blank"> A PDF</a> 
<a href="/somePDF2" target="_blank"> Another PDF</a>
```

Comment: Ok that was a typo in the question. On my actual site I wrote correct HTML, editing question to fix.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably a server side issue seeing how it only comes up when the files are of different sizes.It is unclear without more details.